# What's the best way to store data offline and update it when app goes online

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to do it with NSUserDefaults but unable to show data when i turn app offline.

```
 let params: [String: String] = ["user-login-key" : loginkey , "api-key" : "ebaa3e8571444005cc0b609824e90dc8"]

    Alamofire.request("http://34.210.142.70/isdental/api/v2.0/home/featured", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: params).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                let json1 = data as! NSDictionary

                UserDefaults.standard.set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: json1), forKey: "JsonFeatured")

                let jsond = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "JsonFeatured") as? NSData

                let  json = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: jsond! as Data) as! NSDictionary

                self.CollectionArray = json.object(forKey: "banners") as! NSArray
          }
```

Comment: Are you trying to upload data when app is not in background?

Comment: @SivajeeBattina I am storing data in userdefaults when app has internet connection and is not in background state

Comment: App can persist data in the user’s phone, there are different tools for that task and one of the most popular is the CoreData framework which is the persistence framework provided by Apple.

Comment: just as a side note, if you write `case .success(let value):` instead of `case .success(_):` you don't need to unwrap the `response.result.value` you can use use the value variable like this `let json1 = value as! NSDictionary`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are not checking failure condition.
- if you are offline, Alamofire goes to failure case.

check below code will help you.

```
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                let json1 = data as! NSDictionary
                UserDefaults.standard.set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: json1), forKey: "JsonFeatured")

                let jsond = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "JsonFeatured") as? NSData

                let  json = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: jsond! as Data) as! NSDictionary

              //self.CollectionArray = json.object(forKey: "banners") as! NSArray
            }

        case .failure(_):
            if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "JsonFeatured") != nil){
                if let savedData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "JsonFeatured") as! Data)
                {
                    let  json = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: savedData as! Data) as! NSDictionary

                    self.CollectionArray = json.object(forKey: "banners") as! NSArray

                }
            }
            break

        }
```